# "Back" and "Menu" button disappeared on Javascript Build when using android Theme

Tags: codenameone

After send a javascript build with androidTheme (override the default iOS theme), the output javascript apps works properly, just the "ActionBar" (Back,Menu) button do not appear (yes, there is Commands added into the form)

This make my build javascript apps with androidTheme cannot perform Command action or even "Back" command.

Any idea to solve this issue? If I use default iOS theme, the command is added automatically into the top/bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a continuation of the discussion [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1551#issuecomment-199830817).

Generally commands are **not** portable unless you use the [Toolbar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) API at which point they become cross platform. The iOS theme uses the `StatusBar` style to space the title so you can just set that UIID to 0 but if you build a native iOS app that might be an issue.